# Why is the splat used inside an array definition here?

Tags: ruby, splat

```
def initialize(apps, catch=404)
  @apps = []; @has_app = {}
  apps.each { |app| add app }

  @catch = {}
  [*catch].each { |status| @catch[status] = true }
end
```

In this method from [Rack::Cascade](http://github.com/rack/rack/blob/3d000c5690715be1f1424ce70b08a702c8528d03/lib/rack/cascade.rb), what purpose does the `splat(*)` serve in the `[*catch]` code?

I thought a splat was used in method arguments to indicate when you are going to have an unspecified number of parameters.

Does the splat have a different meaning here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It creates a single flat array for catch

I'm not sure anyone completely understands the splat operator. Many times it removes one level of "arrayness", but it won't remove the last level.

It is possible to get it in this one case, at least. It creates a single level of array for the catch parameter regardless of whether `catch` is a single number or an array of numbers.

```
>> t = [*404]
=> [404]
>> t = [*[404,405,406]]
=> [404, 405, 406]
```

Comment: Good link: http://github.com/mischa/splat. Thanks. Pretty confusing stuff. But "removes one level of arrayness" seems like the simplest way to think about it. Well put.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to understand this is to look what is happening in `irb`.

So let's initialize an empty hash, `@catch`:

```
>> @catch = {}
=> {}
>> @catch.class
=> Hash
```

Now let's see what happens when the parameter `catch` goes to it's default value of `404`:

```
>> catch=404
=> 404
>> [*catch].each { |status| @catch[status] = true }
=> [404]
>> @catch[404]
=> true
```

This gives us a better idea of what is going on. We can see that the `splat` operator is being used to build a `Hash` of responses. The response numbers are being used as a `key` and true is set as the `value`. So no matter how many items we have in catch, we can still build a `Hash`.

```
>> catch=[404, 301, 302, 303, 403]
=> [404, 301, 302, 303, 403]
>> [*catch].each { |status| @catch[status] = true }
=> [404, 301, 302, 303, 403]
>> @catch
=> {302=>true, 303=>true, 403=>true, 404=>true, 301=>true}
```

I hope this helps. Here is a link that helped me out a little bit:

http://theplana.wordpress.com/2007/03/03/ruby-idioms-the-splat-operator/

Comment: Ahh! That's cool! It reminds me of ruby_koans: http://github.com/edgecase/ruby_koans

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at it: an l-value splat is greedy and contains as many corresponding r-values as possible.